# shift row differently based on another column's value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I Want to get a value of tailed-twelve-month(ttm) data, while I only get the data of year-to-date. I want to solve it by adding new columns and then shift different row based on data's month.

the df is like this:

```
date         data     data_ttm
2019-03-31     12       Nan          
2018-12-31     10       Nan         
2018-09-30      8       Nan              
2018-06-30     11       Nan          
2018-03-31      9       Nan         
2017-12-31     12       Nan
2017-09-30     10       Nan
2017-06-30      4       Nan
2017-03-31      7       Nan
```

There are 4 months: 12-31, 09-30,06-30,03-31.

for 2018-12-31, the data_ttm is same as data.

for 2018-09-30, the data_ttm is :data(2018-09-30)-data(2017-09-30)+data(2017-12-31).

I decided to add new column ['month','data_minus'] to solve it

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[datetime.datetime(2019,3,31),'12','NaN'],
                 [datetime.datetime(2018,12,31),'10','NaN'],
                 [datetime.datetime(2018,9,30),'8','NaN'],
                 [datetime.datetime(2018,6,30),'11','NaN'],
                 [datetime.datetime(2018,3,31),'9','NaN'],
                 [datetime.datetime(2017,12,31),'12','NaN'],
                 [datetime.datetime(2017,9,30),'10','NaN'],
                 [datetime.datetime(2017,6,30),'4','NaN'],
                 [datetime.datetime(2017,3,31),'7','NaN']],
                 columns=list(['date','data','data_ttm']))

df['month']=df['date'].map(lambda x: x.month)
df['data_minus']=df['data'].shift(-df['month']/3)-df['data'].shift(-4)
df.loc[df['month']==12,'data_minus']=0  #for the month is 12
df['data_ttm']=df['data']-df['data_minus']
```

and get the error result:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I have tried to search the error, but the situation I searched was not the same like me.

the result I expected is like this:

```
date         data     data_ttm
2019-03-31     12       13         
2018-12-31     10       10         
2018-09-30      8       10              
2018-06-30     11       19         
2018-03-31      9       14          
2017-12-31     12       Nan
2017-09-30     10       Nan
2017-06-30      4       Nan
2017-03-31      7       Nan
```

besides, I think there might be a better way to get ttm data.

---

updated on May 4, 2019

the problem of the code is

```
df['data_minus']=df['data'].shift(-df['month']/3)-df['data'].shift(-4)
```

because the `df['month']` is a series, thus report error.

now I use

```
for i in range(1,5):
    df[df['month']==i*3,'data_minus']=df['data'].shift(-i)#.astype(float)

df['data_ttm']=df['data']+df['data_minus']-df['data'].shift(-4)#.astype(float)
```

to replace the error one. but I think the code is still ugly. is there a better way?

Comment: this line seems suspect `df.loc[df['month']==12,'data_minus']=0  #for the month is 12`. What is this supposed to do again

Comment: if the month is 12, the df['data_minus']=0.
I think the error is ```df['data'].shift(-df['month']/3) ```, I haven't found how to deal with it.

Comment: Looking at the documentation of `pandas.Series.shift` the first argument should be an int and you're providing it a Series. What should be the appropriate shift for that one?

Comment: for the month 9, shift -3;  for month 6, shift -2; for month 3, shift -1.

Comment: I tried this method to get a result, but I think to code is really ugly. 

df.loc[df['month']==12,'data_minus']=0
df.loc[df['month']==9,'data_minus']=df['data'].shift(-4).astype(float)-df['data'].shift(-1).astype(float)
df.loc[df['month']==6,'data_minus']=df['data'].shift(-4).astype(float)-df['data'].shift(-2).astype(float)
df.loc[df['month']==3,'data_minus']=df['data'].shift(-4).astype(float)-df['data'].shift(-3).astype(float)